# how to call dispatch action from a void method in flutter redux

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-redux

I am trying to perform a dispatch action from a method. Here is how I am trying

```
StoreConnector<AppState, AppState>(
                   converter: (store) => store.state,
                   builder: (context, items) => Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(items.rahi),
                        Text(items.mySiteUrl),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('update rahi'),
                         onPressed: (){_updateRahi(store);},
                        ),
                      ],
                   )

                 ),
```

You can see I have cakked `updateRahi` method and inside this method

```
void _updateRahi(store){
  var text = status.text; 
  // want to call dispatch action from here
  store.dispatch('this is some texts');

}
```

I want to call the dispatch action. How can I call from here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';`

```
StoreConnector<AppState, AppState>(
  converter: (store) => store.state,
  builder: (context, items) => Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(items.rahi),
      Text(items.mySiteUrl),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('update rahi'),
        onPressed: (){_updateRahi();},
      ),
    ],
  )
),
```

```
void _updateRahi(){
  final store = StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context);
  var text = status.text; 

  store.dispatch('this is some texts');
}
```